# Paperclip custom interpolation (aka custom path for AWS S3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have three questions related to paperclip and AWS S3.

1) In my model which has paperclip, I have following code:

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
    :url => "/songs/:user_id/:basename.:extension",
    :path => "/songs/:user_id/:basename.:extension"
```

What's the difference between URL and PATH?

2) What is `:basename.:extension`?

3) Let's say there are two models: `User` and `File`. `User` has many `File`. Paperclip path and url  are configured in `File` model.

In `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`, I put below code:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :user_id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.criteria.user_id
end
```

I confirm that above code is working fine. My file gets saved at `songs/5/song.mp3`. I would like to save the mp3 file at `songs/user_id_5/song.mp3`. I tried doing below but it doesn't work.

```
Paperclip.interpolates :user_id do |attachment, style|
    'user_id_' + attachment.instance.criteria.user_id
end
```

How do I make it as I want to ?

Answer (score 0):

1. in S3 language `path` is the Key of your item and `url` is your s3 endpoint

From [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)

> - url: There are four options for the S3 url. You can choose to have the bucket's name placed domain-style (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com) or
>     path-style (s3.amazonaws.com/bucket). You can also specify a CNAME
>     (which requires the CNAME to be specified as :s3_alias_url. You can
>     read more about CNAMEs and S3 at
>     docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?VirtualHosting.html
>     Normally, this won't matter in the slightest and you can leave the
>     default (which is path-style, or :s3_path_url). But in some cases
>     paths don't work and you need to use the domain-style
>     (:s3_domain_url). Anything else here will be treated like path-style.
> - path: This is the key under the bucket in which the file will be stored. The URL will be constructed from the bucket and the path. This is what you will want to interpolate. Keys should be unique, like filenames, and despite the fact that S3 (strictly speaking) does not support directories, you can still use a / to separate parts of your file name.

you can configure the `bucket` or `url` in your config and just pass the `path` (i.e. where to store the file) when you call the method

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: 'mybucket'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: 'aws_region_id',
  }
}
```

2. I don't know
3. You need string interpolation

   ```
   Paperclip.interpolates :user_id do |attachment, style|
     "user_id_#{attachment.instance.criteria.user_id}"
   end
   ```

Comment: so if you have `:path => ":user_id" ...` in your `has_attached_file` method, what is the value of path ?